# Same JSONobject from JSONArray, how to reslove it

Tags: java

My input is like that

All the objects in JSONArray have same data. JSONArray contain soma data of running loop i think it copy the data of last layer to every JSONObject

```
    {"layers":[{"flag":"40","name":"Layer `40","opacity":"-1","bottom":"386","left":"394","right":"410","mode":"layer_mode","top":"370"},{"flag":"40","name":"Layer` 40","opacity":"-1","bottom":"386","left":"394","right":"410","mode":"layer_mode","top":"370"}],"header":{"height":"690","width":"500","color_mode":"3","channels":"3","depth":null,"signature":"8BPS","version":"1"}}
```

**Desired output**

My desired output is also look like that but the data in every JSONObject in JSONArray should be unique or different from eachother
    **my code is like that**

```
package psd;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import psd.layer.PSDLayerPixelData;
import psd.layer.PSDLayerStructure;
import psd.section.PSDLayerAndMask;
import psd.section.PSDHeader;
import org.json.simple.*;

public class TestPSD {

    List<PSDLayerStructure> layers = new ArrayList<PSDLayerStructure>();
    List<PSDLayerPixelData> images = new ArrayList<PSDLayerPixelData>();    
    String signature,color_mode,column,rows,depth,channels,version,img_res,Header,heading,layer_name,layer_top,layer_right,layer_bottom,layer_left,layer_opacity,layer_mode,layer_flag,layer_channel;
    JSONObject header = new JSONObject()  ;
    JSONObject full_info = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject layer_info = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray layer_array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject total_layers = new JSONObject();
    int count=0;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void parser(File f) throws IOException {

    PSDParser parser = new PSDParser(new FileInputStream(f));
    PSDLayerAndMask layerAndMask = parser.getLayerAndMask();
    signature =String.valueOf( parser.getHeader().getSignature());
    color_mode= String.valueOf(parser.getHeader().getMode());
    column =String.valueOf(parser.getHeader().getColumns());
    rows = String.valueOf(parser.getHeader().getRows());
    channels = String.valueOf(parser.getHeader().getChannel());
    version = String.valueOf(parser.getHeader().getVersion());
    header.put("signature", signature);
    header.put("color_mode", color_mode );
    header.put("height", column);
    header.put("width", rows);
    header.put("depth", depth);
    header.put("channels", channels);
    header.put("version", version);

    //System.out.println(full_header);
    //Header = parser.getHeader().toString();
    //full_header.put("header",String.valueOf(Header));
    img_res=parser.getImageResources().toString();  
    layers = layerAndMask.getLayers();
    images = layerAndMask.getImageLayers();
    int i = 0;
    //int j=1;
    for (PSDLayerStructure layer : layers) {
        PSDLayerPixelData pixelData = images.get(i);
        BufferedImage image = pixelData.getImage();
        if (image != null){
            layer_name = String.valueOf(layer.getName());
            layer_bottom = String.valueOf(layer.getBounds().getBottom());
            layer_left = String.valueOf(layer.getBounds().getLeft());
            layer_right = String.valueOf(layer.getBounds().getRight());
            layer_top = String.valueOf(layer.getBounds().getTop());
            layer_opacity = String.valueOf(layer.getOpacity());
            layer_mode = String.valueOf(layer.getBlendModeKey());
            layer_flag = String.valueOf(layer.getFlags());
            layer_info.put("name", layer_name);
            layer_info.put("bottom", layer_bottom);
            layer_info.put("left", layer_left);
            layer_info.put("right", layer_right);
            layer_info.put("top", layer_top);
            layer_info.put("opacity", layer_opacity);
            layer_info.put("mode","layer_mode");
            layer_info.put("flag", layer_flag);
            layer_array.add(layer_info);

            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Images/"+layer.getName() + ".png"));  
        }

        i++;
        count++; 
    }
      full_info.put("layers", layer_array);
      full_info.put("header",header);
    try {

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Faizan\\workspace\\psd_to_html\\psd_to_html\\psd.json");
        file.write(full_info.toString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();
        System.out.println("created");
        //break;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
//  public JSONObject getarray()
//  {
//      return layer_info;
//  }
    public JSONObject layers()
    {
        return total_layers;
    }
    public JSONArray getlayers()
    {
        return layer_array;
    }
    public JSONObject getlayer()
    {
        return layer_info;
    }
//  public String getheading()
//  {
//      return heading;
//  }
//  public String getresoucre()
//  {
//      return img_res;
//  }
    public JSONObject getinfo()
    {
        return full_info ;
    }
    public int count()
    {
        return count;
    }
//  public String getheader()
//  {
//      return Header;
//  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I'm lost. What is the problem that you need help with? What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: thanks for asking, i try to explain the question,

Comment: if you see the input given above the objects in array have same properties   but i want different property of of each object how can i do it ?